# How to store n number of inputs into an array using mysql in express.js

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

Hi I a beginner to the web development
I wanted to accept n number of the instance(n is inputted by the user) from the user and then store those values in an array-like structure so that my frontend can have access to it. Can this be done using mysql ?. I was reading StackOverflow posts that mentioned that it is not a good idea to use MySQL for this. However I am already kind of deep into my project so I want to clarify this.

Is this feasible using MySQL?

Comment: please clarify your que and share some code what you have did so far .?

Comment: sure checkout https://github.com/lcherone/autorm could do `await (new database.row('table_name', req.body)).store()` though you should always validate inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to store something like object or array of something 
let's say that in your front end there is a form with input and button
where the input is Add More Columns and the input is value so in your backend you will get an array of objects like

```js
[
        { question: '1', answer: 'Answer1' },
        { question: '2', answer: 'Answer2' },
        { question: '3', answer: 'Answer3' },
        { question: '4', answer: 'Answer4' }
]
```

you can make a table

id | userId | payload

where id is generated by SQL
userId that you injected in the token (or something else to relate the user with his payloads)
and payload that contains the information that you need to store

```
const saveUserPayLoads = async (req, res) => {

    const { payloads } = req.body;
    const { id } = req.user
    const data = []
    for(payload of payloads) data.push(DBModule.create({ payload: JSON.stringify(payload), userId: id }))
    return res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Done',
      success: true,
      data
    })

}
```